# LinqPad: Directly referencing ObjectContexts in a Class

Tags: c#, linqpad, objectcontext

I'm constantly C&P'ing stuff between LinqPad and VS. And, I just want to make the transitions as neat as possible.

So in LinqPad, you can directly reference an ObjectContext within the main function or any custom function. But if you include a class in there, you can't directly reference any ObjectContext in the class's functions/methods.

One thing you can do is this:

```
class MyClass{

    ISessionTable<Category> Categories;

    public MyClass(ISessionTable<Category> categories){
        Categories = categories;
    }

    public void MyClassFunction(){
        Categories.Count().Dump();
    }
}
```

Is there any other neater way of doing this? The above sort of dictates how I should be coding in VS as well, which is something I'd like to avoid (if possible).

**UPDATE:**

In my non-LinqPad C# code, I can't always just pass in the ObjectContext to a class due to various reasons. So to be more specific for my question, is there a way to access "Categories" (following the above example) without passing it in to the class? In other words, is there some kind of global way of access?

Comment: Define "neater." What is it you don't like about this approach? This looks like a pretty good example of dependency injection to me.

Comment: There really is no "neat way" to spit out debugging/object-state in "real code" ... or was the `Dump()` just extraneous? :) An extension method could always be defined to turn it into an effective NOP, or send it to a log, but... ick.

Comment: "Neater" in the sense that it'd reduce the amount of refactoring I'd have to do when I port stuff between LinqPad and VS. I guess it's really specific to people's needs. And yes that Dump() has nothing to do with anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just came up with a way to circumvent the problem through a design approach.

Let me clarify my own workflow or reason for using LinqPad. I use LinqPad to test out classes, lots of them. Many of them have to have access to the database. Since Copying and pasting chunks of code (whole classes) is less time-consuming than refactoring, I try to reduce the amount of refactoring needed when porting code in-between LinqPad and VS. So, I try to keep the two versions of code to be as exact as possible.

So the solution I came up with is to use a third arbitrary class to hold ObjectContext's. Then to test out a class in LinqPad would involve the following code:

```
void Main()
{
    DB.Categories = Categories;

    MyAwesomeClass awesomeness = new MyAwesomeClass();
    awesomeness.DumpNumOfCategories();
}

class MyAwesomeClass {

    public MyAwesomeClass(){

    }

    public void DumpNumOfCategories(){
        DB.Categories.Count().Dump();
    }

}

class DB{
    public static ISessionTable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

This way, the class in testing (e.g. MyAwesomeClass) can be kept the same in both LinqPad and VS versions. No more refactoring, and no more polluting the class constructor. Class DB will require two different versions but it doesn't really need to be changed too much once implemented.